# Radio button acts strangely with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this code to generate a list of radio buttons :

```
                <div ng-show="user.role != 'COLLABORATEUR'">
                <div class="form-group row clearfix">
                    <label for="roleRadio" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Role</label>
                    <div class="checkbox-demo-row"  ng-repeat="role in roles">
                    <div class="input-demo radio-demo row">
                            <label class="radio-inline custom-radio nowrap">
                                <input type="radio" id="roleRadio" name="roleRadio" ng-model="user.role">
                                <span>{{role.name}}</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
```

**roles** : `[{name:"SUPERCHEF"},{name:"CHEF"},{name:"COLLABORATEUR"}]`

**user.role** : `{role:"SUPERCHEF"}`

So as the date states the role `SUPERCHEF` should be selected by default but NO BUTTON IS SELECTED and when I click on any given button the last one is always selected and when I click a second time I can click wherever I want.

Comment: You are repeating ID...

Comment: you mean `id="roleRadio"` ? Cause I removed it and it's the same deal

Comment: Also remove the `for="roleRadio"` as well.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT] Set the ng-value of the radio input:

```
<input type="radio" name="roleRadio" ng-model="user.role" ng-value="{{role.id}}">
```

And you need to set the default value, for example:

```
$scope.user = {
    role: 'SUPERCHEF'
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but instead of `value="{{role.id}}"` I needed to use `ng-value"{{role.id}}"`

Comment: This all is there in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D).